# Increase number of worker_connections on Beanstalk nodejs environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to increase the number of possible `worker_connections` of my nginx on my Beanstalk nodejs server.
I followed the documentation and created a `proxy.config` file in my `.ebextensions` folder at the root of my project.

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |

      worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;
      events {
        worker_connections  50000;
      }
```

I re-deployed my project but still get this error
`[alert] 19144#0: 1024 worker_connections are not enough`.

**EDIT:**
I was looking at the documentation for Amazon Linux 1, so here is my new problem: [Increasing worker_connections of nginx on Beanstalk nodejs environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343544/increasing-worker-connections-of-nginx-on-beanstalk-nodejs-environment)

Comment: What EB platform are you using? Based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: @Marcin Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` is for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you are using **Amazon Linux 2** you should be using  `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), to customize nginx.

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;
events {
  worker_connections  50000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed not looking at the right part of the documentation.
I now get a `[emerg] "worker_rlimit_nofile" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

Comment: @httpete I'm not expert in nginx settings. Thus not sure what is the correct syntax for this option. But you were using settings for Amazon Linux 1, not 2, thus your options in `proxy.conf` were not recognized at all.

Comment: @httpete What happens when you remove `worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;` line?

Comment: Same problem with the other lines `[emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:3`