# Increasing worker_connections of nginx on Beanstalk nodejs environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to increase the number of possible `worker_connections` of my nginx on my Beanstalk nodejs server (**Amazon Linux 2**).
I followed the documentation and created a file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` with this content:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;
events {
  worker_connections  32768;
}
```

When deploying I get the error:
`[emerg] "worker_rlimit_nofile" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`

When commenting this line I still get:
`[emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:3`

Comment: Your extension is incorrect. It should be `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, it is just a typo in my question, the file name was correct. Still got the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these are top level settings, and you have to **overwrite main** `nginx.conf` file. You do this by creating `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` config file. In that case, you can remove `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

You can try the following  `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;                                      
pid /run/nginx.pid;
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.         
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 32768;                                               
}
http {                                                                
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.                   
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;  
        error_page 404 /404.html;        
            location = /40x.html {       
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;                                      
            location = /50x.html {       
        }
    }
}
```

If this does not work, you can ssh into your EB instance, check what is the actual, default `nginx.conf` (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) for your EB environment, copy it, and use in `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Thank you that was it. Indeed `include conf.d/*.conf;` is inside the `http` directive so it could not work.

Answer (score 6):

@marcin's answer above is correct. Making updates to worker_connections requires modification via the `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` file. For other's reference, as of July 2021, AWS is using the following as a default for nginx.conf on Elastic Beanstalk v2 and Amazon Linux 2:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    131435;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Simply add the above file to `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` and modify the worker_connections value to the desired value. [AWS docs are lacking on this currently](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.example), but I've requested they make further updates.