# Replace default nginx config elastic beanstalk NodeJS Amazon Linux

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My NodeJS Application is running on Elastic Beanstalk, platform: **Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux**.

There is an issue worker_connections is not enough.

```
1024 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream
```

This is the default worker_connections set in elastic beanstalk nginx.conf file

**nginx.conf**

```
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024; # <-- want to change this number
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  
  log_format  healthd '$msec"$uri"$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"$http_x_forwarded_for';
  include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I want to increase `worker_connections` number.

To do that it means I need to replace default `nginx.conf`, but I can't find a way to do this.

In AWS doc, there is only a guide to override nginx config inside `http` section.

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing worker\_connections of nginx on Beanstalk nodejs environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343544/increasing-worker-connections-of-nginx-on-beanstalk-nodejs-environment)

Comment: No I'm using Amazon Linux 1, not Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html#nodejs-platform-proxy.alami) explain  how to do it for AL1. Just like for AL2, you have to **overwrite entire nginx file** (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) using `.ebextensions/proxy.config`.

You can try with `.ebextensions/proxy.config`:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        user  nginx;
        worker_processes  auto;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
        events {
          worker_connections  1024; # <-- want to change this number
        }
        http {
          include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
          default_type  application/octet-stream;
          access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
          
          log_format  healthd '$msec"$uri"$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"$http_x_forwarded_for';
          include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
          include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        }


  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      service nginx stop 
      service nginx start

container_commands:
  removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

Comment: does it work? In the docs. I only see it can override the content inside `http` part?

Comment: @TanDat You can try and check.

Comment: @TanDat How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: it does not work :(